# Rasterize produces wrong result - R

Tags: qgis, raster, r, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a polygon in R using teh `rasterize` function but the output is not correct. I am comparing the result with the output produced by the `rasterize` tool available in `QGIS`

May data are:

```
> Fields2
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1293 
extent      : 219807.1, 230535.3, 4097488, 4104080  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=30 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 4
names       :  ID,       area, id_2,      mean 
min values  :   1, 100044.627,    1, 1001.9653 
max values  : 999,   9990.943,    1,  998.5807
```

[image]

```
> test
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 660, 1074, 708840  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 219800, 230540, 4097480, 4104080  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=30 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : fortesting 
values      : 126.7778, 1965.884  (min, max)
```

I am using the following command `poly_to_raster<-rasterize(x=Fields2, y=test, field="mean")`

The results looks like this:
[image]

The white pixels do not have any value and are NA. Confirmed by looking at the pixel info of this raster in QGIS

[image]

I thouhgh there is someting wrong wity the shapefile I am using as reference in `rasterize`, but when I do the same process in QGIS, I get the right result:
[image]

[image]

--- EDIT ---

The `mean` attribute comes from an `extract` function

```
meancalc<-extract(S_images_ts[[1]], Fields, fun=mean)
Fields@data<-data.frame(Fields@data, mean=meancalc)
```

For confirmation

```
> str(Fields2$mean)
 num [1:1293] 275 1350 442 430 1364 ...
```

Comment: I would suspect something is not quite right with the polygons (eg they are encoded clockwise instead of anticlockwise, or something), but its impossible to tell without the data. If you want identical behaviour in R as QGIS, then use the `gdal_rasterize` function from the `gdalUtils` package, which calls the same command-line function as listed in the QGIS dialog.

Comment: I noticed something unusual with the min and max values of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Why is min area > max area, and min mean > max mean?

Comment: Well spotted - I wonder if these are character values? Try `Fields2$mean2 = as.numeric(as.character(Fields2$mean))` and rasterizing with `mean2`...

Comment: Note that instead of printing an sp-object if you do `library(raster)` and  `summary(sp_object)` it will tell you the class of the column and you should see immediately if its not numeric.

Comment: I have edited my question to add more information. True, the min/max value is strange to me. `mean` is numeric although I have tried the option `as.numeric` to double check and the same result is obtained. Any way to share the `shapefile` to have a closer look?

Comment: Managed to make it work using `gdal_rasterize` from `gdalUtils` but still wondering what should be the issue `rasterize`

Comment: If you can zip the .shp .shx and .dbf or save the R object using `saveRDS(thing, "thing.rds")` and make the file available via Dropbox or Box with a sharing link. Other file sharing sites are available.

Comment: @Spacedman, here the OneDrive link. It is a zip folder with the `shapefile` https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoJcCA_nP7xqgx2eemvp8SjIz0Ft

Comment: That shapefile doesn't have a `mean` field, and we don't have the image to do the `extract` on (which is why I suggested saving the R object). That shapefile rasterises okay on its "area" field though.  `e = raster(extent(Fields2), res=c(2000/250)) ; rf = rasterize(Fields2, e, "area")`

Answer (score 1):

The last feature in your shapefile is a bit.... off - it looks like a union of all the polygon lines:

```
> plot(Fields2[1293,])
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure that's messing up `rasterize`. Not sure how QGIS is coping, but I reckon if you can figure out where this has come from and remove it then you'll stop having problems in R.

Hmmm actually it looks like the polygon of the negative space that isn't the first 1292 polygons within the rectangle, but its convoluted form perhaps means `rasterize` isn't sure what's the inside and what's the outside...

And indeed if you read the shapefile in with `sf::st_read` and test with `st_is_valid` you get to see that the last feature is not valid.

Comment: You are right, `Fields2[1293,]` comes from a `union` operation that I did in QGIS. I had those field boundaries and I need a polygon to be created in the empty spaces in between. For that I used the `shapefile` of the study area and the `union` operator